# find xml node by attribute value(as3)

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I use this code in as3 in order to find node with specific id value but it is working for 2 depth

```
elementsToDraw = elementsList.*.(@id=="hello");
```

For example at this xml node can be found

```
<nodes>
 <node id="d">
  <node id="hello">
  </node>
 </node>
</nodes>
```

but this code get no results at

```
<nodes>
 <node id="d">
  <node id="d1">
   <node id="hello">
   </node>
  </node>
 </node>
</nodes>
```

What should I write for searching in any depth element with id="hello"?

Comment: How about writing a recursive function that looks for attributes in descendants too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `..` notation to search for all node :

```
var elementsList:XML=<nodes>
 <node id="d">
   <node id="hello"/>
   <node id="d1">
   <node id="hello">
   </node>
  </node>
 </node>
</nodes>;

var xl:XMLList=elementsList..*.(@id=="hello");

trace(xl.toXMLString());
```